# Plot a *rotated* Parabola in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I know how to plot a horizontal and/or vertical parabola.  Is there an easy way to plot a rotated parabola, i.e., one that contains an x-y term, e.g.,

3x<sup>2</sup> + 2 sqrt(3) xy + y<sup>2</sup> - 2y - 3 = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
syms x y
ezplot('3*x^2 + 2*sqrt(3)*x*y + y^2 - 2*y - 3')
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `syms x y`, which requires Symbolic Toolbox. The `ezplot` command works without it.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't know ezplot could be used in this way.  I looked in Mastering MATLAB and MATLAB's help, and I still couldn't figure it out.  They only had examples for y = f(x) type functions.